# Why my code didn't read the receiver side chat?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

i made a chat app, but the activity didn't read the receiver chat when i open the message activity while the data is there in the database.

this is android application that linked to firebase realtime database.

this is the code for readMessage from the database to be view in activity.

```
private void readMessage(final String senderID, final String receiverID){
    chats = new ArrayList<>();

    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            chats.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                assert chat != null;
                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(receiverID) && chat.getSender().equals(senderID)){
                    chats.add(chat);
                }

                messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this,chats);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Current output from the apps:

[image: this is current output]

This is data hold in database currently.
There should be "hello" as reply from receiver
[image: database input]

Comment: are you trying to chat among devices

Comment: yes exactly @notTdar

Comment: you need a backend server or you can use firebase cloud function with node js, then only you can send across devices. Check the documents thoroughly https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/ and a sample which I created https://github.com/Hemen07/Groupy

Comment: there's a video example in following. i followed exactly the code, but somehow mine didn't load the message received. there could be logic error or something within the code above. i'm not looking for other solution. just want to my code above

Comment: if you are exchanging messages between devices, you can't do that without above instruction, why don't you read android docs to understand before coding?

Comment: what if exchanging message between accounts ?

Comment: Do try and tell us

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: is it possible to have kotlin and java in one application ? @AlexMamo

Comment: @Izz Sure, you can call Java methods from Kotlin and vice versa.